# Generate Chirp Signal using Arduino & Si5351

Tags: signal-processing

I allow myself to join you to know if it would be possible to have additional information concerning the Si5351 module.

My need would be to use this module to emit a pseudo-periodic signal (aka **chirp**) looking like this ([YouTube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAUY1FEojjc)) *- a chirp between 1 600 Hz
and 300 Hz and with a sweep repetition rate of two to four times per second -* ?

I already have an Arduino Nano for driving as well as the Si5351 module, but I wanted to get your opinion on my project, because I have trouble finding information regarding the generation of this kind of signal ? Is this already achievable ?

In advance, thank you for your answer.

Comment: as I see it in the datasheet, minimal frequency is 0.0025 MHz so 2.5 kHz

Comment: Requesting opinions is off topic. Generating the chirp can be done with the Arduino already. What prevents generating the chirp with the Arduino and why would a clock generator be necessary?

Answer (score 0):

It is theoretically possible to get the frequency spectrum you want. Even with the Si5351 whose minimum frequency is 2.5 kHz. The chip has at least 2 channels with which two frequencies (f1 and f2) can be generated at the same time. If these are mixed with a non-linear component, new frequencies are created (| f1-f2 | and f1 + f2). The frequency f1 + f2 then has to be filtered out with a low-pass filter. With a suitable choice of the two frequencies, the desired lower frequencies can theoretically be generated in this way.

However, a problem could be the frequency generator used in the chip. So-called PLLs are used there. These need a certain amount of time to switch from one frequency to the next. This could cause problems with a chirp signal.

In summary, I would join @Justme's suggestion and recommend that you use Arduino's tone generator. This is designed for the low frequencies and rapid frequency changes should not be a problem either. Since the tone generator generates a square wave that contains many overtones, you should think about a simple low-pass filter. There is enough information on this on the web.

If you use the interrupt that is used by the tone generator for other purposes, you can also use a second Arduino (possibly an inexpensive clone) to "chirp" and control it with the "master" arduino.